# Adobe AEM form & tables data - how to reference non-displaying column

Tags: adobe, aem

We have large tables to display in Correspondence Management forms and want to condense some columns in to one such as Age / AgeFrom / AgeTo / AgeUnits / DOB.  I do this in the attached script on 'calculate'.

The trouble is that the column must exist to be referenced.  However through the UI there doesn't appear to be any way to hide the column.  You can set its width to 0 and the border around it has a de-emphasized look.  Though it holds some width.  And then if you need to add columns (because stupidly you deleted them when trying to fix this problem!), the "there is not enough space" error occurs.

Is there a best way to make zero width columns in AEM tables?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing this question I went back to it and tried again and worked out a solution.  And I'm happy to know if there is some better solution.

1. Firstly don't delete columns
2. Right-click on the table in the Data View and `Generate Fields` (or just drag it to the page).  This will have every column.
3. This next step is slow and tedious and this is where an answer with a more efficient method would be nice.  However it works to provide the desired outcome.

   1. One by one click on each column's arrow and choose `select column`
   2. `Window (menu) > Object > Cell (tab) > Presence = Invisible`
   3. `Window (menu) > Layout > Width = 0.0001mm` and press `return`

I haven't experimented with different values to `0.0001mm` except that `0` does not have the same effect.

Now each column is hidden.  It can be restored by working with it from the `Hierarchy` pane.

[image]